# What does "of" + noun do in the beginning of the sentence as subject?

Tags: word-meaning, sentence-structure, prepositional-phrases, grammaticality-in-context

I am reading a book and it has a grammar structure that I've never seen: ***Of* + noun as subject of sentence**:

[image]

Usually it should be **noun + *of* + noun**, The sentence's meaning does not really change when replacing it to "one particular importance" or "one of the particular importance", but since in a science book fancy style is not important, I think it means more than that. [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/of) does not give any example of this. So what is the name of this grammar structure and what does it do? Can I use it in the middle of sentence?

Comment: "Of particular importance" is not the subject. This is an example of subject-dependent inversion where the subject is the NP "the fact that such three-dimensional reflections again preserve symmetry", and the PP "of particular importance" is predicative complement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When something is **of importance** it is important.

When something is **of particular importance** it is especially important.

The phrase is predicated (a fancy word for "said") of something:

{something} is "of importance".

Putting a phrase such as **of importance** at the beginning of the sentence is a way of emphasizing the phrase in order to tell the reader to pay special attention to what follows.

> Staying hydrated  when exercising in the heat **is** *of particular importance*.
>
> *Of particular importance* when exercising in the heat **is** staying hydrated.

These two predications:

> {a} **is** {b}

and

> {b} **is** {a}

are equivalent.

Comment: why should `a is b` equal `b is a`?

Answer (score 0):

This sentence

> Of particular importance is the fact that such three-dimensional reflections again preserve symmetry

could also be worded in any of the following ways:

> The fact that such three-dimensional reflections again preserve symmetry is of particular importance
>
> The fact that such three-dimensional reflections again preserve symmetry is a fact of particular importance
>
> The fact that such three-dimensional reflections again preserve symmetry is particularly important
>
> Particularly important is the fact that such three-dimensional reflections again preserve symmetry

(Note: You can't say "one particular importance", because "importance" is a mass noun.)

Oxford Living Dictionaries [defines](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/of) "**be of**" as follows.  (Note: you have to scroll down the page until you find **be of**.)

> Possess intrinsically; give rise to.

It gives examples such as:

> ‘this work is of great interest and value’
>
> ‘The rise in the rate of suicide amongst young people is of constant concern to our agency.’
>
> ‘Listen and make the other person feel that what he or she is saying is of interest to you.’
>
> ‘Many of the calls were of a difficult nature from distressed families with moving reports of missing people.’
>
> ‘The software will be of interest to schools and museums, as well as town planners.’

There are some further examples on the page.

Comment: Why does the sentence use only "of importance" instead of "being of importance"?

Comment: @Ooker because "of importance" is not part of the subject. The version of "be" in that sentence is the word "is". The position of the subject is moved or inverted.